# boost::posix_time::from_iso_string allows erroneous input

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

Strangely,

```
std::cout << boost::posix_time::from_iso_string("20120927T062299");// 99 seconds!
```

yields `2012-Sep-27 06:23:39`, i.e. overflown seconds wrap into the next minute. Is it really an expected behaviour? If so, how can I force the functiion to fail in such circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different library implementors have different ideas of what should result in an error and of what severity.

The simple answer is, if the string comes from user input, check it yourself before providing it to any function expecting a properly-formatted string. This is generally a good idea anyway. In this case, a regular expression check would be fairly simple.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no regex that could check if 2012.02.29 is a valid day or not. I could reimplement the parsing myself, but it defeats the whole purpose of ISO standards and library functions implementing them...

Comment: After some investigation into `from_string()` implementation I found that it's only the time part which is allowed to parse improper values. So, the point in my previous doesn't hold, and yes - the time part can easily be regexed.